# HTML: how to upscale an image with <img> and keep the aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, image

Currently I am using `img` with no other constraint than `max-width` and `max-height` and I like the fact that when I use a bigger image my browser will downscale the image to fit it completely in its area (button, div, whatever) while keeping the image aspect ratio.

But for the case where the image is smaller I would like the browser to upscale the image (so that it takes the whole width OR height) while keeping the aspect ratio.

I tried playing with `width:100%` or/and `height:100%` but of course these will stretch the image, which is not what I want.

Here is an example.
The first image is big and will downscale properly.
The second image is small and doesn't upscale... I don't know how to upscale it properly.
That is my question!
I would like a pure CSS solution, no javascript if possible.

Note: I dont know what the image exact size is and I want to downscale if its too big and upscale if it's too small.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <button type="button" style="width:256px; height:256px">
            <img src="http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/d4g_logo_global.jpg" alt="Smiley face" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%">
        </button>

        <button type="button" style="width:256px; height:256px">
            <img src="http://static.autodesk.net/etc/designs/v2171/autodesk/adsk-design/images/autodesk_header_logo_140x23.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%">
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to do `max-width` and `max-height` Just use `width:100%;` instead.

The image will automatically maintain it's aspect ratio if you only define the width.

Here is a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Ea26r/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button type="button">
        <img src="..." alt="Smiley face">
    </button>
    <button type="button">
        <img src="..." >
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so after some back and forth in the comments I think I have a better grasp of what you're looking for. Rather than using `<img>` tags inside the buttons, we can just use CSS to apply a `background-image` to the button then use `background-size: contain;` to scale the photo regardless of it's orientation. Something like this:

HTML

```
<button id="button1" type="button" style="width:256px; height:32px">
</button>
```

CSS

```
#button1 {
    background-image: url('http://www.url-to-image-here.com');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Now, keep in mind that IE8 and below do not support `background-size:contain;` so this solution is not perfect, but if you are not concerned about support for older browsers, then this should get you what you need. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/68VRk/

Comment: Yes you need it otherwise you get over scaling.
Check this one here:
http://jsfiddle.net/FLcHd/

I changed the image to a vertical image to show how it can get complicated...
The middle button is your suggestion.
The last button is better but I get stretching because of the width:100%...

The good answer would be with left and right letter boxing.

Comment: Then add a class to both orientation possibilities and for tall images, change it to `height:100%;` See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KTduh/

Comment: I wish I could know the image in advance but in my context I don't.  This jsfiddle was a simplification.  In my case I don't know the image in advance...

Comment: And for the record, the image can be wide but if the canvas (button, div, etc) is even wider than you need to use the "tall" class.  Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/P9NA3/3/

Comment: @Éric Ah, I see. I've updated my answer with another solution for you to try.

Comment: Thanks Dryden, the "background-size: contain" is really useful.

Comment: @Éric Cool, good to hear. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it worked out for you!